# How can I have Clustered caching in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching

How can I store date on my server cache but when I use load balancer with 2 or more hoster server, then data cached on one server is not available on another server.
How can I have distributed or Clustered caching in asp.net mvc?

Please help me asap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try AppFabric Caching it is very simple to integrate and easy to use.

you can use following link for further details.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/308508/AppFAbric-Caching-Extension